# How can multiple timeouts be prevented from running simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

If an image is clicked it changes the image 3 seconds later. But if I click the image multiple times within that three seconds, it starts a new timer. Especially if I click the image 5 times in a second, it won't change for three seconds, but when those three seconds are up it will change 5 times in a second.

Is there a way to do an if statement saying, If this function is running kill the current running function and start a new function. This way it will ignore the first 4 clicks of the image and only run the fifth click, or only run the first click and skip the four other clicks.

Here is the code:

```
 function auto_change(a,b) { // a is the current image and b calls a function that makes certain image visible, it works but need to fix the multiple clicks problem 
if (document.getElementById(a).style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(b,3000);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Closely related: [How can I prevent onclick event from firing more than once until an asynchronous task is complete?](/q/16804566/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var waitTimer = null;
function auto_change(a,b){
  if (document.getElementById(a).style.visibility == 'visible'){
    waitTimer && clearTimeout(waitTimer);
    waitTimer = setTimeout(b, 3000);
  }
}
```

Store the timeout instance and check if it already exists. If it does, clear it and reset it. if not, just set it. this will make the *last* click the only responsible one.

Other variations:

1) Click is specific to which `a` is clicked:

```
var waitTimer = [];
function auto_change(a,b){
  if (document.getElementById(a).style.visibility == 'visible'){
    waitTimer[a] && clearTimeout(waitTimer[a]);
    waitTimer[a] = setTimeout(b, 3000);
  }
}
```

2) React on first click:

```
var waitTimer = null;
function auto_change(a,b){
  if (!waitTimer && document.getElementById(a).style.visibility == 'visible'){
    waitTimer = setTimeout(b, 3000);
  }
}
```

3) Hybrid of first click and specific to `a`:

```
var waitTimer = [];
function auto_change(a,b){
  if (!waitTimer[a] && document.getElementById(a).style.visibility == 'visible'){
    waitTimer[a] = setTimeout(b, 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Helps one problem but starts a new problem! I click and it changes. And If I click on it two times it changes only once. But after that when  I click it no longer works. This error pops up which doesn't pop up for others: waitTime is not defined

Comment: @Patrick: typo on my part. I had `clearTimeout(waitTime)` (supposed to be `clearInterval(waitTimer)`.)

Comment: Yup, that was it. Should have caught that myself. Now that I know it works, I have to understand it. Any help here?

Comment: Every call sets up a timeout, but the difference is you check if one already exists before declaring it. This gives you ~3 minutes to clear the initial timeout and redeclare it (so you don't end up with multiple declarations, and, therefore multiple executions).